# How to stop timer while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

So I setup a `System.Timers.Timer` and have a handler for the `Elapsed` event. It works as expected.

However, if I want to debug the code that is called within the elapsed handler; the timer will continue generating additional events.  Thus, I can't single step through the code because timer events stack up on top of each other.

The current workaround is to call `Stop` on the timer upon entering the handler and `Start` when leaving. However, that is not how the system is supposed to work so that is a temporary fix.  I was wondering if there is a way to configure the debugger to halt the timer while debugging.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want you can wrap this into a [`#if DEBUG` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) 
or you can use [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx).

Comment: +1 - For the Debugger.IsAttached property. I think I like that better than #if.

Comment: to be honest: that depends on what you want to achieve - with the #if thing you don't have the code in your release-version at all, where the other option will be a unused code-path there.

Answer (score 5):

In your `Timer.Elapsed` event handler, maybe you can use some preprocessor directives to include code that stops and starts (or disables and enables) the timer:

```
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        (source as Timer).Stop();
        // or
        (source as Timer).Enabled = false;
#endif

        // do your work

#if DEBUG
        (source as Timer).Start();
        // or
        (source as Timer).Enabled = true;
#endif
    }
```

Comment: I have the Stop and Start as a temporary workaround. I'm not really a fan of preprocessor directives. But if that is the only way that might be the route I take.